# MDX queries in SSMS vs calculated membersin cubes performance

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have some MDX queries with calculated members than when I run them in SSMS run very fast.
But when I implement these calculated members in the cube and  run them, it's very slowly.
Any ideas of this behavior?

This is the query that runs smoothly in SSMS, but it takes forever when I query the cube from Excel or Tableau (against the same calculated members in the Cube)

```
with member [Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months] 
as
    sum(  
       lastperiods(3, ancestor([Date].[Calendar].currentMember,[Date].     [Calendar].[Calendar Year Month])), [Measures].[Sales Month BUM]
    )
    /
    count(
       nonempty(lastperiods(3, ancestor([Date].[Calendar].currentMember,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year Month])), [Measures].[Sales Month BUM])
    )    

member [Measures].[CoverageSalesBUM] 
as
  sum([Measures].[Unrestricted BUM])
  /
  sum([Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months] )   

select  non empty { [Measures].[Unrestricted BUM] , [Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months] } on 0 
 ,non empty([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Date] , [Plant].[Plant].[Plant],[Material].[Material].[Material].[149249] ) on 1
 from [InventCoverage]
```

Comment: Maybe try rebuilding aggregations after creating the calculated measures in the cube.

Comment: Can you post a few sample MDX queries and the identical calls you added to the cube?

Answer (score 0):

(More of a code review than an answer, as I don't know much about cube scripts so cannot comment on what you might need to do to the cube)

Is you first calculation not a re-invention of the function `Avg`?

Also in you second calc why do you need to apply `Sum()`? If this is the aggregation set in the cube then no need to explicitly say `Sum`. Also apparently `Divide` is quite a recent introduction and maybe marginally more efficient

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months] AS 
    Avg
    (
      LastPeriods
      (3
       ,Ancestor
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year Month]
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sales Month BUM]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[CoverageSalesBUM] AS 
    Divide
    (
      [Measures].[Unrestricted BUM]
     ,[Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Unrestricted BUM]
     ,[Measures].[Sales BUM Avg 3Months]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Date]
     ,[Plant].[Plant].[Plant]
     ,[Material].[Material].[Material].[149249]
    ) ON 1
FROM [InventCoverage];
```